# Need responsive equal height div tags with different width

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How we can get responsive equal height div tag with different width? 
For example if screen of 100% I need 80% to be one div and remaining other div but their heights should be same. 
I have tried so many plugins but no use. I am using bootstrap4 now.?

Please find the sample html file that i am using.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>equal height</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-lg-9 col-xs-12" style="background-color:darkseagreen">
                <h2>equal height</h2>
                <h2>equal height</h2>
                <h2>equal height</h2>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-lg-3 col-xs-12" style="background-color:lightyellow">

                <h2>equal height</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share your html

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Thanks for responding, please find the attached snippet, actually i am new to this. But very interested to learn the things. please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

On parent element add `display: flex`, and `align-items: stretch`.

```
(...)
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="display: flex; align-items: stretch;">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-lg-9 col-xs-12" style="background-color:darkseagreen">
                    <h2>equal height</h2>
(...)
```

Downside of this approach is that you'll need to use media queries to put one child below another on smaller screens (with `display: flex` they'll always be one besides the other)

Comment: Thanks for the answer it's worked perfectly. Can you, please guide me how to write a media query. actually i am new to this.

Comment: Good place to start is here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

For this specific case, you'll need to add in css
`@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    /* For mobile phones: */
    #id-of-parent {
         flex-direction: column;
    }
}`